# How to uninstall Pure-FTPd on centOS?

Tags: linux, centos, sftp, ftp

as mentioned in the title I want to remove Pure-FTPd from my centOS server. Can anyone tell me how to do this? What is the command line that remove pure-ftpd? I have centOS 6.5 64-bit. Appreciate it.

Comment: . . .Did you even look at the [documentation](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement) ([man page](http://linux.die.net/man/8/yum)) and/or [ask Google](https://www.google.com/search?client=safari&rls=en&q=Remove+package+CentOS&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8)? See http://serverfault.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2):

If it was installed using the [yum](https://access.redhat.com/site/solutions/9934) (the CentOS package manager)

```
yum remove pure-ftpd
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to Iain's answer, you can use RPM with:

```
rpm -e pure-ftpd
```